# Access AWS locally from AWS using PaaS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pythonanywhere, paas, amazon-elasticache

I will be using the [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) PaaS service. It is using AWS on us-east-1 for all its EC2 instances.

They don't offer Redis and I plan to create a regular AWS Redis instance using Elasticache.

Ideally I would like to connect to the Redis instance from the paas using local internal network of AWS.

Do you know if this kind of setup is possible? That is benefit from local network between paas AWS hosted to regular EC2 instances?

(The paas allows external connections.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is not very clear. Are you saying that you wish to have your (non-AWS) PaaS service connect to an Elasticache cluster in an AWS VPC? Would you want that connection to go across the Internet, or via a VPN connection? What do you mean by "local network between paas AWS"?

Comment: Hello the Paas is hosted on aws. So i guess in their vpc.     Indeed i would want to access access my redis in my vpc from the paas vpc. And as a direct acces from aws to aws  just as i would within my own aws vpc.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple AWS VPCs can connect to each other via [VPC Peering](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/vpc-peering-overview.html). The VPCs must be in the same region and have non-overlapping IP addresses.

However, this requires changes within both VPCs to connect to each other. It is unlikely that PythonAnywhere would want to modify their configuration for you. (But, by all means, ask them!)

An alternative is to connect to your Redis cluster within your own VPC, but do it via a **Public IP address**. The traffic will travel between VPCs across the 'edge' of the Internet -- that is, it won't go on the Internet proper, it will just transit within AWS' network if it is in the same Region. So, it *is* using the "local internal network of AWS", but via a Public IP address.